# Query parameters in Zipkin

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I may have missed it, but how do save query parameters in zipkin?

My service is running:

- spring-boot = 2.0.4.RELEASE
- spring-cloud = Finchley.SR2
- spring-cloud-starter-zipkin = 2.0.2.RELEASE

I'm missing host too, but I suspect that is because I'm running services in docker containers.

***update 8/13/2019***

I make a call to https://test-service.mydomain.com/api/conn/parallel2?repetitions=20&delay=10000&bypassTokenCache=true&overrideTokenRefreshSeconds=10

Notice in the trace I'm missing host and query parameters. Is there any way to record those values in zipkin?

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I completely don't understand your problem. You can't connect to Zipkin? You can't see query params for a span that wraps your REST call? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure - sorry for being to vague. I have zipkin working and it's catching traces from a number of different microservices.  The problem is I can't see the query parameters.

Comment: Have you logged them? If not then bo wonder cause sleuth doesn't log query params out of the box

Comment: That is it. I was not sure what sleuth was recording out of the box.  Are there any examples of how to add them to the tracing?

Comment: Read the documentation on how to add a tag. Then inject a SpanCustomizer and use it to pass additional tags with query params